# How do I access value in lua table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have following lua code that prints out the Mac Addresses of a device.

```
local sc = Command.Scan.create() 
local devices = sc:scan() 
local topicMac
local list = {}

for _,device in pairs(devices) do 
   print(device:getMACAddress())
   list[device] = device:getMACAddress()
end
  
topicMac = list[0]
print(topicMac)
```

Since there are several addresses and they are listed in a table, I would like to save only the first one into the local variable "topicMac". I tried reaching that first value by adding the first index (0 or 1) in the array.

Why do I get `nil` as return?

Comment: Both using 0 or 1, results as "nil" on the console

Comment: If you want to access a variable outside of its local context, don't declare it `local`.

Comment: Even when not declaring it locally, return is "nil"

Comment: Do you still need the whole `list`, or can you throw out everything except the first item? If you don't need the whole `list`, @Senor's answer is correct.

Comment: There's a lot of missing information here: what does `devices` look like? what is the "first" MAC address to you, or do you just want *any* mac address form the list? why do you need a list in the first place if you just want the first address?

Answer (score 1):

The `next` keyword can be used as a variant function to retrieve the first index and value out of a table

```
local index, value = next(tab) -- returns the first index and value of a table
```

so in your case:

```
local _, topicMac = next(list)
```

Comment: Is that right? It seems quite arbitrary to have it return the second value. A slight hack you can use, if you intend on throwing away the rest of the table, is using break to terminate the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: @WhatIsProtocoll: Lua tables are unordered. They don't really have a first or second value.

Comment: @luther only when the keys aren't ordinal, otherwise you can use `ipairs` to loop in an ordinal fashion. I'm guessing the `devices` table will have numbered keys, so try using `ipairs` along with what I mentioned above if you want a shot at getting the very first key.

Comment: If `devices` is an array, they can just do `local topicMac = devices[1]:getMACAddress()`. Either way, you don't need a loop to get a single, arbitrary item from a table.

Comment: Breaking the loop is a good idea, I settled on luthers declaration which works just a well in just one line. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

"First" and "Second" depends on what we have as keys. To check it just use print():

```lua
for k,d in pairs(devices) do 
  print(k,' = ',d:getMACAddress())
end
```

If keys are numbers, you can decide which is "first". If keys are strings, you are still able to make an algorithm to determine the first item in the table:

```lua
local the_first = "some_default_key"
for k,d in pairs(devices) do
  if k < the_first then   -- or use custom function: if isGreater(the_first,k) then
    the_first = k
  end
end
topicMac = devices[the_first]:getMACAddress()
print(topicMac)
```

If keys are objects or functions, you can't compare them directly. So you have to pick just any first item:

```lua
for _,d in pairs(devices) do 
  topicMac = d:getMACAddress()
  break
end
print(topicMac)
```